# Seeking for QEMU emulable Harvard RISC CPU

Tags: compiler-construction, qemu

I am currently working on a project for my Computer Architecture course at university. The task involves selecting a programming language, in my case, a Lisp-like one, and writing a compiler for it. Additionally, I need to implement a CPU emulator capable of executing the machine code generated by the compiler. The specific requirement is that the CPU must be RISC and based on the Harvard architecture.

While I could design a simple CPU from scratch for educational purposes, I prefer to explore existing real CPU architectures that fit the specified constraints. Using this approach I would eliminate the need to design the ISA, and I could leverage tools like QEMU to test the machine code execution against my emulator.

I am seeking recommendations for a RISC Harvard CPU that can be emulated with QEMU. If you have experience with such CPUs or have come across relevant information, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

During my search, I considered the following architectures:

ARM Cortex M3 – The developer's page indicates Harvard architecture, but upon reviewing the [memory model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZffxD.png) in the user manual, I observed a single flat address space. It appears that the separation between Code and SRAM regions does not enforce independent instruction and data memory access, neither does it guarantee instruction and data separation. I am unsure if this still qualifies as a genuine Harvard architecture.

RISC-V – I referred to a [paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2019sp/schedule/slides/06-cpu-pre-bw.pdf) (p.14-15 and p.27) describing a RISC-V CPU with a modified Harvard architecture, featuring a separate data memory unit (on p. 27). However, upon examining the specifications, I encountered similar doubts regarding the flat address space.

I may be misunderstanding the Harvard architecture concept. I initially thought that after linking, two distinct files would be created for instruction and data address spaces. Could you please provide clarification on this?

Comment: You should ask your university for clarification about their requirements for the task, not us...

Comment: There are no real machines that use a "pure" Jarvard architeure, as it is not useful for a general-purpose machine, as there's no way to change the program in such a machine.  So any real machine has some ability to treat the instruction store as data store.